# CSS3 transition on box-shadow at :active

Tags: css-transitions, css, pseudo-class

Is it possible to use :active for animating a change in box-shadow with duration and delay.

I have a change in color on :hover with duration. Apparently the same approach doesn't work for box-shadow.

I tried add class through js. I tried setting duration in the :active class and in the main class. I tried `transition: box shadow 1s` `transition-duration: 1s`. And some more stuff.

the full code is at codepen http://cdpn.io/pKJmC

So, any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it a default state to transition from. You already have `box-shadow` on the circles but no *inset* `box-shadow`. Add an inset box-shadow set to zero on your circles:

```
.ball1,
.ball2,
.ball3 {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #222, 0px 10px 20px -10px #222;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just starting with transitions. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the property name is box-shadow. In your question you written it without the hyphen.

One more thing, you can't transition to or from an auto property. So you'll have to define a box-shadow: none; on your default state if you want this to work